# Каким членом предложения является "нет"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, члены-предложения

> Его уволили или нет?

"Нет" — какой член предложения? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Слово "нет" в этом предложении является сказуемым, по смыслу равно "не уволили" — употреблено во избежание повтора. Союз "или" в этом случае соединяет предыдущий глагол и частицу "нет" — как однородные сказуемые.

Другое дело, радоваться этому или нет (= "не радоваться").
Пусть только США определятся, дадут они денег или нет (= "не дадут").
В конце следующего сезона мы сможем сказать, удалось это нам или нет (= "не удалось").

[НЕТ](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Net-16554.html), частица
Употребляется вместо сказуемого с отрицанием, а также вместо словосочетания или целого предложения с отрицанием, когда они противопоставляются предыдущему. *Возник спор: одни утверждали, что нужно строить дорогу, другие — что нет. Она думала: придёт он или нет.*