# Пунктуация в известной цитате А. С. Пушкина

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, как, цитата

Отвечала на вопрос ([Каким членом предложения является “нет”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462406/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)); в словаре Ушакова попалась такая пушкинская цитата (статья о слове ["проваливать"](http://endic.ru/ushakov/Provalivat-58980.html)):
**Хочешь жить как мы, милости просим, — нет, так убирайся, проваливай.**

Снова у того же Ушакова (статья о слове ["нет"](https://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=35872)):
**Хочешь жить, как мы, милости просим, нет — так убирайся, проваливай.**

Еще одна версия (слово ["убираться"](https://books.google.ee/books?id=JnKkBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA698&lpg=PA698&dq=%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BC%D1%8B,%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC,%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82,%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F,%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=nkDKDaaAsF&sig=ACfU3U0Pbe-joJs9fW-PSIxiEn--7pVKWg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD0OWZ_ebsAhVGrosKHQtyB1o4FBDoATAHegQIChAC#v=onepage&q=%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%2C%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9&f=false)):
**Хочешь жить как мы, милости просим — нет, так убирайся, проваливай!**

Я понимаю, что это цитата "из девятнадцатого века" и что она кочует из словаря в словарь.
Но все-таки — где же правильно сегодня поставить запятые и тире? Подскажите.

Comment: "Хочешь жить как мы — милости просим, нет — так убирайся, проваливай". Это моя версия.

Comment: Римма, я задал ваш вопрос Грамме.ру. Ниже см.их ответ.

Comment: Римма Михайловна, если вы не верите, лично вам могу выслать доказательства.  В отличие от г-н behemothus,я никогда ничего не придумываю.

Answer (score 3):

> Но все-таки — где же правильно сегодня поставить запятые и тире?

Здесь нет однозначно правильного ответа - и это единственное, что можно принять у Сержа в ответе якобы "Граммы".

Здесь накладываются две вещи. Во-первых, авторская пунктуация. С ней, насколько понимаю, сложно, мало того, что Пушкин не очень-то и соблюдал правила пунктуации, в черновиках особенно, так еще и автограф совершенно нечитаемый, там расшифровывать надо каждое слово.

И второе, это, конечно, современная рекомендация о нежелательности двух тире в одном предложении (в тех случаях, когда это может вызвать затруднения при прочтении).

Что касается изменений в правилах по сравнению с пушкинской эпохой, то, насколько знаю, существенных изменений в части, касающейся нашего примера, не произошло. Так что ваше уточнение "по современным правилам" излишне. Вопрос "как правильно" вполне законен и без уточнения.

Другое дело, что однозначного ответа, как уже говорил, тут нет. И дело не в самодеятельности корректоров, как уверяет Серж, а в объективном отсутствии формального приоритета у правил. И второе - в неоднозначности самой грамматической структуры этого предложения, взятого из подчеркнуто разговорной речи.

Давайте от печки.
У нас есть два правила и одна рекомендация по постановке тире. О рекомендации уже сказал, два непарных тире крайне нежелательны в тексте, если это приводит к двусмысленности.

Правило об эллиптическом и интонационном тире.

> Тире ставится для указания места разделения простого предложения на
> словесные группы, чтобы подчеркнуть либо уточнить смысловые отношения
> между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или
> порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94#pp94)

Замечу сразу, что тут речь идет о тире между членами или группами внутри одного предложения.

> 2. Тире, которое ставится между членами предложения для выражения неожиданности или   > для обозначения логического ударения, также имеет
>    интонационный характер: И щуку бросили — в реку (Кр.); Через несколько
>    минут загремели цепи, двери отворились, и вошёл — Швабрин (П.).

Там же. В общем-то те же исходные условия.

И второе правило. О тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении.
[§ 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151)

Не буду копипастить, оно очень длинное, но сводится  к тому, что тире **обязательно** ставится в случае противопоставления или неожиданного перехода в месте распадения составного предложения на два простых.

Других правил, претендующих на применения в нашей фразе, я не вижу.

И все бы ничего, но в сочетании с упомянутой рекомендацией правила вступают в противоречие. Тире во всех трех случаях не поставить. Какое из них выбрать?
Мне кажется очевидным, что второе правило, о тире в бессоюзном сложном, имеет больший приоритет, поскольку правило это более императивно.

Так что, если мы принимаем за постулат, что предложение наше - бессоюзное сложное, то "правильным" написанием будет

***Хочешь жить как мы, милости просим — нет, так убирайся, проваливай.***

Для запятой перед тире мотивов не вижу. Кстати, это именно тот момент пунктуации, который изменился со времен Пушкина. Раньше использование тире с запятой как единого знака было более распространено. Равным образом я не вижу мотивов (кроме редакторско-корректорской традиции) и для вариантов, разбираемых в вопросе. То есть такой вариант можно считать условно-правильным. Условность в том, что он базируется на логике, а не на прямой формулировке правила, а с логикой (моей) можно и не согласиться.

Но тут возникает два возражения. Во-первых, можно ли признать предложение бессоюзным сложным. Честно говоря, не знаю, но другого не вижу.

А во-вторых, в таком виде фраза совершенно нечитаема. И вот тут-то каждый, в том числе и корректор, вправе решить для себя, что важнее, правила  или читаемость текста.

Если второе, то я полностью за вариант, тут (и не только тут) уже предлагавшийся.

***"Хочешь жить как мы — милости просим, нет — так убирайся, проваливай"***
Я бы рекомендовал этот абсолютно прозрачный вариант, если есть хоть малейшее основание для неприменения правила о тире в бессоюзном сложном.

В той или иной степени все розенталевские  условия можно обойти, но вот с этим как быть?

> 5. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в первой > части обозначается условие совершения действия, о
>    котором говорится во второй части (в начале первой части можно
>    добавить союз если):

Там же.

У Лопатина, кстати, еще более жестко, но в принципе то же самое.

> § 130. В бессоюзном сложном предложении ставится тире:
>
> 1. если между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения устанавливаются
>    сопоставительные и противительные отношения: На дворе в морозном пару
>    краснело солнце — в доме было тепло. На дворе палил летний зной — в
>    доме было прохладно (Бун.); Это не конь строчит — сердце мое стучит
>    (Сн.); Хотели снова назначить его председателем — нельзя (Расп.);
>    Соседей звал истошно — не пришли, затаилися (Т. Толст.);

Мне кажется, тут прямое указание на то, что тире перед "НЕТ" в нашей фразе не может быть ни опущено, ни заменено запятой ни при каких дополнительных предположениях. Разве что оспорить, что мы имеем дело с бессоюзным сложным.

Тем не менее выбор для меня - только из этих двух вариантов. Остальное явно не по правилам.

Comment: *Если второе, то я полностью за вариант, тут (и не только тут) уже предлагавшийся. "Хочешь жить как мы — милости просим, нет — так убирайся, проваливай"* — мне тоже очень нравится этот вариант!

Answer (score 2):

Ответ Граммы.ру

Ваш пример оформления фразы из «Бориса Годунова» — настоящий камень преткновения для редакторов. Вы привели еще не все возможные способы оформления. Встречаются также такие:
Хочешь жить как мы — милости просим; нет — так убирайся, проваливай!
Хочешь жить как мы — милости просим. Нет — так убирайся, проваливай!

Разнобой в пунктационном оформлении обусловлен тем, что структура предложения требует постановки трех тире (Хочешь жить как мы — милости просим и Нет — так убирайся, проваливай, где тире должно разделять части бессоюзного сложного предложения с условными отношениями; а также тире между этими бессоюзными предложениями, между которыми устанавливаются отношения противопоставления), однако это невозможно (ср.: Хочешь жить как мы — милости просим — нет — так убирайся, проваливай!).

Как следствие, редакторы вынуждены выбирать для постановки тире тот случай, который они считают наиболее важным, заменяя остальные тире запятыми. В связи с этим наиболее оправданным кажется вариант:
Хочешь жить как мы, милости просим — нет, так убирайся, проваливай!
Это тире оформляет не только противопоставление, но и стилистический слом фразы (книжная первая часть и разговорно-просторечная вторая часть). Именно такое оформление является наиболее распространенным при издании «Бориса Годунова».

Comment: Ответ в том, что "грамма" не знает, как надо? Да и грамма ли это? Пруф будет?!

Comment: @Danis Предложенная вами правка невозможна, поскольку весь текст у Сержа - это (якобы) цитата, пусть и ненадлежащим образом оформленная

Comment: @behemothus спасибо. В следующий раз буду внимательней

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за ответ с "Граммы". (У Вас, вижу, там контакты налажены?)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова и еще. Просто к сведению. gramma.ru как сайт уже год как ушла в мир иной. убедитесь: gramma.ru  Откуда у Сержа контакты с потусторонними мирами - это только он знает. Во всяком случае, элементарная порядочность требует от автора уточнений, откуда у него информация, на которую невозможно дать пруф.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо, конечно, но в контексте разговора об ответе якобы "граммы" я совершенно не претендую на какую-то значимость своего ответа. Речь о другом. Для меня неприемлем тот способ подачи информации, которым постоянно грешит Серж. В данном случае отсылка к "грамме" как к заведомо авторитетному источнику (с чего бы это?) и при этом отсутствие каких либо пояснений, откуда этот текст. По мне так или уж не пиши вовсе, что это грамма, или уж объясни, что получено по личным каналам от такого-то и такого-то лица. Авторитетность, понятно совсем другая.